How to import data from this file (see in URL from EC)
Link of the data set in tsv
https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/api/dissemination/sdmx/2.1/data/env_ww_genp?format=TSV&compressed=true
I downloaed it, extracted it to tsv file, opened it with Notepad and can imagine the data frame structure but dont't know how to import it.
You can download it and see the tsv file or below is part of the data set
freq,ww_gtd,substance,unit,geo\TIME_PERIOD  2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010    2011    2012    2013    2014    2015    2016    2017    2018    2019    2020    2021 
A,DIS,BOD,O2_TD,AT  :   :   :   :   :   :   :   :   15.00   :   15.00   :   12.60   :   12.50   :   13.59   :   12.57   12.90   12.78   16.99 
A,DIS,BOD,O2_TD,BE  22.36 e 21.28 e 101.67 e    11.16 e 9.62 e  32.01 e :   :   :   :   34.89 e 31.13 e 34.89 e 32.38 e 27.07 e 30.01 e 31.78 e 26.49 e 28.13 e :   :   : 
A,DIS,BOD,O2_TD,CY  :   :   :   :   0.45    0.50    :   :   :   :   :   :   :   :   :   :   :   :   0.19    :   0.22    : 

Please help.
I would like to import it, get variables, column, rows.
Thank you.

read.csv(..., sep="\t")?

This text file has two separators inside. The first seprator is a comma that separates the first 5 variables (freq, ww_gtd, substance, unit, and geo) and the second separator is a tab (\t) that separates the time period columns.
You can check from readLines.
head(readLines("estat_env_ww_genp.tsv"), 2)
    [1] "freq,ww_gtd,substance,unit,geo\\TIME_PERIOD\t2000 \t2001 \t2002 \t2003 \t2004 \t2005 \t2006 \t2007 \t2008 \t2009 \t2010 \t2011 \t2012 \t2013 \t2014 \t2015 \t2016 \t2017 \t2018 \t2019 \t2020 \t2021 "
    [2] "A,DIS,BOD,O2_TD,AT\t: \t: \t: \t: \t: \t: \t: \t: \t15.00 \t: \t15.00 \t: \t12.60 \t: \t12.50 \t: \t13.59 \t: \t12.57 \t12.90 \t12.78 \t16.99 "

You can try reading this using readr::read_tsv (or read.csv with the tab separator) and deal with the first 5 variables later.
df <- read_tsv("estat_env_ww_genp.tsv")
head(df, 3)

# A tibble: 3 × 23
freq,ww_gtd,substance,uni…¹ `2000` `2001` `2002` `2003` `2004` `2005` `2006`
  <chr>                       <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 A,DIS,BOD,O2_TD,AT          :      :      :      :      :      :      :     
2 A,DIS,BOD,O2_TD,BE          22.36… 21.28… 101.6… 11.16… 9.62 e 32.01… :     
3 A,DIS,BOD,O2_TD,CY          :      :      :      :      0.45   0.50   :     
# ℹ abbreviated name: ¹​`freq,ww_gtd,substance,unit,geo\\TIME_PERIOD`
# ℹ 15 more variables: `2007` <chr>, `2008` <chr>, `2009` <chr>,
#   `2010` <chr>, `2011` <chr>, `2012` <chr>, `2013` <chr>, `2014` <chr>,
#   `2015` <chr>, `2016` <chr>, `2017` <chr>, `2018` <chr>, `2019` <chr>,
#   `2020` <chr>, `2021` <chr>

You can separate the data in the first column with the following:
df |>
  tidyr::separate(col=1, sep=",", into=c("freq", "ww_gtd", "substance", "unit", "geo"))
# A tibble: 1,880 × 27
   freq  ww_gtd substance unit  geo   `2000`  `2001`  `2002`  `2003` `2004`
   <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr> 
 1 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD AT    :       :       :       :      :     
 2 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD BE    22.36 e 21.28 e 101.67… 11.16… 9.62 e
 3 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD CY    :       :       :       :      0.45  
 4 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD CZ    :       :       :       :      :     
 5 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD EE    :       :       :       :      :     
 6 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD FI    :       :       :       :      :     
 7 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD LT    :       :       :       :      :     
 8 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD LV    8.09    6.04    5.94    5.51   7.05  
 9 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD MT    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00  
10 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD RO    :       :       :       :      :     
# ℹ 1,870 more rows

The colons (:) and unwanted "e" in each of the time period columns can be removed if required.

There's also eurostat package that you can use for search and download:
library(eurostat)
search_results <- 
  search_eurostat("Generation and discharge of wastewater by pollutant", 
                  type = "dataset")
dplyr::glimpse(search_results)
#> Rows: 1
#> Columns: 9
#> $ title                       <chr> "Generation and discharge of wastewater by…
#> $ code                        <chr> "env_ww_genp"
#> $ type                        <chr> "dataset"
#> $ last.update.of.data         <chr> "26.07.2023"
#> $ last.table.structure.change <chr> "03.01.2024"
#> $ data.start                  <chr> "2000"
#> $ data.end                    <chr> "2021"
#> $ values                      <dbl> 20669
#> $ hierarchy                   <dbl> 5

env_ww_genp <- get_eurostat(search_results$code)
#> Dataset query already saved in cache_list.json...
env_ww_genp
#> # A tibble: 20,669 × 7
#>    freq  ww_gtd substance unit  geo   TIME_PERIOD values
#>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr> <chr> <date>       <dbl>
#>  1 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD AT    2008-01-01    15  
#>  2 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD AT    2010-01-01    15  
#>  3 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD AT    2012-01-01    12.6
#>  4 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD AT    2014-01-01    12.5
#>  5 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD AT    2016-01-01    13.6
#>  6 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD AT    2018-01-01    12.6
#>  7 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD AT    2019-01-01    12.9
#>  8 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD AT    2020-01-01    12.8
#>  9 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD AT    2021-01-01    17.0
#> 10 A     DIS    BOD       O2_TD BE    2000-01-01    22.4
#> # ℹ 20,659 more rows

Created on 2024-04-24 with reprex v2.1.0
